# QGIS layer export to KML limited to 2 fields

Tags: qgis, google-maps, fields-attributes, kml, export

I'm successfully exporting my layer to KML using the Right click > Export > Save Features As.. window. I then check the 13 fields I want to export, and proceed without problem. But when I import this KML file in Google My Maps, the data table only contains 3 fields (Name, Description and 1 of the fields I checked).

Is there a way to work around this limitation?

Answer (score 2):

I found out why some fields would not follow : their content was NULL. I put a 0 in all the fields of only one feature and all the checked fields successfully exported and now show up in the destination attribute table! So most of the data cells can be NULL, but if at least one feature contains a value in a specific field, this field will be exported.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is a version problem: on QGIS 3.6 it works as expected:

- `Right click` -> `Export` -> `Save Features As..`
- select all fields you want to export:

[image]

- import in Google My Maps:

[image]

all fields are present.